# No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`

Tags: json

No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.

what should I do to handle this error

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a Device first.
Use the following command:

```
avdmanager create avd -n myDevice -k "system-images;android-29;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"
```

However you will have to find `avdmanager`. For me, this is in `..\SDK\cmdline-tools\latest\bin` path but might be in different location in your PC.